# Flutter - Custom AppBar with image and moving elements

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new with Flutter and I'm trying to get a specific UI behaviour but without success. I have tried using a "SliverAppBar" with a "FlexibleSpaceBar" and I can get the app bar to show an image (except when it's compressed) but I can't get the rest of the elements to behave as intended.

The goal is to achieve the behaviour shown [here](https://gfycat.com/GeneralFreshCivet).

Scroll down:

- Body text scrolls under the bar
- Title moves from body to bar while changing color and then size
- Bar image gets smaller
- Some elements disappear behind the bar
- Some elements disappear in front of the bar

Scroll up:

- Bar extends, image gets bigger until the user releases it

Comment: You need to use Sliver widgets for that

Comment: Maybe not the best task for a beginner? This will require a deep understanding of slivers, custom rendering (probably directly using `RenderBox` and scrolling. The question is a bit too broad to be answered. As a start, take a close look at all sliver widgets, experiment with them, look at the source code. Then try to write your own, play with rendering etc. Ask more specific questions on the way ;)